# Не удается подключиться pgAdmin 4.29 к удаленному серверу PostgreSQL 9.2, 9.6, 12

Tags: postgresql, администрирование, pgadmin4, pgadmin

На удаленном сервере *Windows 2008 R2* установлено три сервера *PostgreSQL*: **9.2**, **9.6**, **12**

Для всех трех **pg_hba.conf**

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

@remove-line-for-nolocal@# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
@remove-line-for-nolocal@local   all             all                                     @authmethodlocal@
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            @authmethodhost@
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 @authmethodhost@
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
@remove-line-for-nolocal@#local   replication     @default_username@                                @authmethodlocal@
#host    replication     @default_username@        127.0.0.1/32            @authmethodhost@
#host    replication     @default_username@        ::1/128                 @authmethodhost@

host    all             all             0.0.0.0/0               md5
host    all             all             ::0/0                   md5
host    all             all             all                     md5
```

Пробовал без последней строчки - на результат не влияет.

Для всех трех **postgresql.conf** (порты 5432, 5433, 5434 соответственно для 9.2, 9.6, 12)

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 100
```

Через pgAdmin 4 удается подключиться к конкретной пользовательской базе на сервере:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
База, к которой подключались, выделена желтым значком, остальные просто видны. При попытке подключения к ним появляется ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
----------------------------------
Unknown error
----------------------------------
                                OK
```

Но при подключении к базе postgres (т.е. ко всему сервере), аналогично локальному, появляется пустая ошибка и не удается сохранить настройки подключения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Error saving properties
----------------------------------
Unable to connect to server:
----------------------------------
                                OK
```

А если все таки извернуться и сохранить настройки, то при попытке подключения к серверу несколько раз запрашивается пароль, а затем сервер разрывает соединение.

Подключение pgAdmin локально на сервере проходит корректно ко всем трем серверам - проблема только с удаленным подключением к серверам.

Правила брандмауэра:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все найденные статьи и видео в интернете не дают решения - у них ошибки нет, у меня есть
Пробовал pgAdmin из состава pg server и отдельно скачанный с официального сайта.
Пробовал удалять каталог %AppData%/pgadmin/

Как решить проблему?
Может pgAdmin нужно как-то дополнительно сконфигурировать?
Или конфиги (*pg_hba.conf*, *postgresql.conf*) серверов у меня неправильные?

Comment: О, это у вас pgadmin поломанный. Вы его на чем держите, запускаете?

Comment: А вас базы(ы) хоть запущены? Приведённый pg_hba синтаксически некорректен, с таким база откажется стартовать.

Comment: @Мелкий у меня точно такой же глюкодром наблюдается с теми же симптомами. psql при этом работает

Comment: Сервера с такими конфигами стартуют - службы запущены. К отдельным базам на серверах подключиться удается как pgAdmin так и через другой софт, например QGIS. У меня pgAdmin 4.29 x64 под windows 10 скачанный отдельно с официального сайта. Пробовал чистить папку %AppData%/pgadmin/ - не помогло. Ни какие настройки pgAdmin не менял.